# Resuming screen after ssh-ing into server

Tags: gnu-screen, xterm

I get the following error when I try to resume the only running **screen** session on a ubuntu machine (after sshing to it from my Mac OS X 10.9)

```
ubuntu@ip-10-252-164-249:~$ screen -r
Cannot find terminfo entry for 'xterm-new'
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: What happens when you run `screen -ls`?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345675/screen-cannot-find-terminfo-entry-for-xterm-256color ?

Comment: @ryekayo: I get the following message;

There is a screen on:
 13819.irc (03/07/2014 07:28:19 PM) (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-ubuntu.

Comment: @fyu: I saw that; did not help me in solving the problem. I see a similar error message but with xterm-new instead of the color problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if $TERM is set on the OSX end of the connection, and passed through to the Ubuntu end.  The workaround would be (on the Ubuntu end, and presuming you are using bash):

```
TERM=xterm screen -x
```

which would override $TERM when reattaching the screen session.  You could of course do

```
export TERM=xterm
screen -x
```

depending on how you want to work with it.

Comment: Noticing the use of "-r" above, I see that screen's manpage seems to imply that "-x" is not the same.  (I've been using "-x" for reattaching for a long time - either should work).